# IAM Policy Deny Deregister AMI

Tags: amazon-iam

I am using the policy below to prevent a particular user to deregister an AMI image but it doesn't work. I think that I have given correct region and AMI.

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": 
     {
        "Action": "ec2:DeregisterImage*",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:region::image/image id"
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a late reply, but for anyone who wonders what the problem is: A lot of EC2 actions do not support resource based permissions. That means you have to write "*" as the resource or the policy won't have any effect. DeregisterImage is among these actions:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html#ec2-api-unsupported-resource-permissions